# Cannot find module 'angular2-json2csv',Cannot find module 'file-saver'

Tags: angular, npm-install

I have Angular 4 project commited on svn running with plugin **angular2-json2csv** , when I run it a log appears saying : Cannot find module ***'angular2-json2csv'*** and Cannot find module ***'file-saver'***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to save installed plugins in the project via **--save**

```
npm install file-saver --save
```

instead of
`npm install file-saver`

and `npm i angular2-json2csv --save`
instead of

```
npm i angular2-json2csv
```